# jQuery - selector keeps changing

Tags: jquery-selectors

This is how my selector looks like:

```
$("#testMyCard-123 > div.test1 > div.test3 > tr > h4");
```

Everything is working for some time, but then the number `123` changes to `456`. And my selector stops working, as `$("#test-123...` becomes `$("test-456...`

What would be the correct way to include at once, like maybe `$("#testMyCard-123...contains('testMyCard'...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [attribute starts with](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) pseudo selector using `id` as the attribute:

```
$("[id^=testMyCard] > div.test1 > div.test3 > tr > h4");
```